# Is there any way to cache POST requests with or without Okhttp but not removing Retrofit implementation?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

try to cache post request data but not able to cache. Try to work with get request code working fine.

Comment: `Try to work with get request code working fine.` show how you did

Comment: tried, but not working.
Can you please give me an example with get request.

Comment: please read again: `show how you did`